# laravel blade how to send my post to the form

Tags: php, laravel

```
@forelse($posts as $post)
 <th>{{$post->id}}</th>
 <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="javascript:PopUpShow()"><i class="fas fa-adjust" style="color:green;"></i></a> 
@endforelse

<div class="b-popup" id="popup" style="display: none;">
     <div class="hiding-form">
<form action="/breakingposts/{{$post->id}}" method="post" name="breakingpost" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

I have form and foresle loop with posts. How Can I send my post to form when I clicking on my button inside a forelse a loop. Is it possible ?

Comment: you can not get the post outside forelse loop, you can get a particular post by calling it with index like `$posts[0]->id`

Comment: yes, but I want to make only one form, just change data for every post

Comment: you can do it with javascript easily, keep your data on buttons, then on button click retrieve data from button and populate form

Comment: Can you help me with that, I'm not sure how to take data in js and then pull it again into form. I was trying to make function which is taking $data . But It didn't work.

Comment: you can do it many ways, like you can send an ajax request to server with post id, then populate the form with returned data, or you can keep your data in button then retrieve it, try one as you feel comfort, I will definitely help if you stuck

Comment: pass csrfr token,